# jquery if statement formatting

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a jquery if statement that doesn't quite work the way it should, I think it's close, but doesn't seem to quite want to work:

I'd like it to following the following:
if it's a ios device I want it to do one thing, if it's a window with a height greater then 500 px but less then 830 then do the other thing and if it's neither of those things do the third thing

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);


if(agentID) {
    $("#about_container").css({
        height: $(window).height() + 500
    });
    $("#about_main_header_container").css({
        paddingBottom: (($(window).height() - $("#about_content_total").outerHeight(true)) /2) - 50
    });
    $("#services_wrapper").css({
        height: $(window).height() + 190
    });
    $("#services_main_header_container").css({
        paddingBottom: (($(window).height() - $("#services_container").outerHeight(true)) /2) - 10
    });
}
else if ($(window).height() > 500, $(window).height() < 830) {
$("#about_container").css({
    height: 830
});    
$("#services_wrapper").css({
    height: 830
});
$("#services_main_header_container").css({
    paddingBottom: 160
});
$("#about_main_header_container").css({
    paddingBottom: 130
});
}
else {
    $("#about_container").css({
        height: $(window).height() - 65
    });
    $("#about_main_header_container").css({
        paddingBottom: (($(window).height() - $("#about_content_total").outerHeight(true)) /2) - 175
    });
    $("#services_wrapper").css({
        height: $(window).height() - 100
    });
    $("#services_main_header_container").css({
        paddingBottom: (($(window).height() - $("#services_container").outerHeight(true)) /2) - 175
    });
}
```

Comment: ...how do you want it to work?

Comment: What is your question?  Can you give us more details on "doesn't quite work"?

Comment: if it's a ios device I want it to do one thing, if it's a window with a height greater then 500 px but less then 830 then do the other thing and if it's neither of those things do the third thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if ($(window).height() > 500, $(window).height() < 830)
```

is not right, it should be:

```
else if ($(window).height() > 500 && $(window).height() < 830)
```

In javascript, `a,b` will just return `b`.

Comment: hmmm, but they're not quite the same thing?